# C Program: Enter Number, Different Output Number

Tags: c

I've been learning C quite a while now. I downloaded Visual Studio which is new to me to use (normally I use Code::Blocks) to compile a program. Here is my problem, I wrote just a basic code as followed:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int main()
   {
        int a;
        printf("Hello World!\n");
        printf("How are you doing?\n");
        printf("Put in your ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("Your ID is: %d\n",a);

        return 0;
   }
```

When I run it for example; putting in the ID number: 1234567890, 
it showed 1234567890 exactly same.

But When I put in longer number: 12345678900,
it showed 3755744308.

I either forgot or cannot figure out what's wrong with the code or program, so I want to ask for an advise.

Thank you

Comment: You say "C" and you tag "C++". Which one is it? It looks more like C than C++.

Comment: It's C , sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Your number is too large to fit into a 32-bit (my assumption) integer.

Comment: The type `int` is typically 32 bits on most platforms today, which means it will have a range from around minus two billion to plus two billion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` in your case is 4 bytes long datatype. The number `12345678900` is represented in hex as `0x2DFDC1C34` which as can be seen occupying more than 4 bytes. So it is truncated to 4 bytes `0xDFDC1C34` which is exactly `3755744308` in decimal.

Comment: So, I need to change "int" to "double" and %d to %f or%lf for longer bytes??

Comment: Better change to `long` and`%ld`

Comment: @EugeneSh., `long` isn't guaranteed to go beyond the range of `int`. `long long` is guaranteed to be big enough to store this number.

Comment: @chris Actually I would suggest to use the uintXX_t types from`stdint.h`, but I guess not in this context..

Answer (score 0):

You got integer overflow. If you input a  number that doesn't fit into `int` data type, it'll be truncated to the biggest `int` value possible.

If you want to input *very* big numbers, use `unsigned long long` or `long long` or `unsigned long`.

(This is C++, not C, but it's easy to understand)

```
#include<iostream>

#define B_N 1e20
using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint64_t uint;
    int64_t i64;
    unsigned long long ull;
    unsigned long ulong;
    long long ll;
    long l;
    int i;

    uint=B_N;
    i64=B_N;
    ull=B_N;
    i=B_N;
    ulong= B_N;
    ll=B_N;
    l=B_N;

    cout<<"uint64_t: "<<uint<<endl;
    cout<<"int64_t: "<<i64<<endl;
    cout<<"ull: "<<ull<<endl;
    cout<<"ulong: "<<ulong<<endl;
    cout<<"long long: "<<ll<<endl;
    cout<<"long: "<<l<<endl;
    cout<<"int: "<<i<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For example, [Codepad](http://codepad.org/iEaAJmhI) will show you lots of overflow warnings.

Comment: ".. it'll be truncated to the biggest int value possible" - I (and compiler) do not agree..